# How can I make a hidden dropdown menu with only CSS?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I want to make a hidden dropdown menu that has another hidden dropdown menu within it. I have been able to hide the whole menu within `.dropbtn`but I would like to hide the `.dropdown-content` within `.dropbtn1`so that I would just get the flags with the countries' respective name when I hover over the main button and the links when I hover over each flag. Being a newbie, I have been unable to accomplish this. This is what I have done:

```css
.pais {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: red;
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-paises {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-paises a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-paises {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Menú</h2>
<p>Pasa el cursor por encima del botón para ver el menú.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Negocios por País</button>
  <div class="dropdown-paises">
    <div class="pais">Alemania</div>
    <button class="dropbtn1"><img src="http://chilesymaiz.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/german-flag-small.gif" alt="Alemania" width="100" height="50"></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#hola-mexico">Hola México</a>
      <a href="#komali-tortillas">Komali Tortillas</a>
      <a href="#la-mexicana-bremen">La Mexicana Bremen</a>
      <a href="#la-tortilla">La Tortilla</a>
      <a href="#mexgrocer-alemania">Mexgrocer</a>
      <a href="#delicious-food-and-drinks">Delicious Food and Drinks</a>
      <a href="#mex-al">Mex-Al</a>
      <a href="#tequila-hacienda">Tequila Hacienda</a>

      <div class="dropdown-paises">
        <div class="pais">Dinamarca</div>
        <button class="dropbtn1"><img src="http://chilesymaiz.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/dane-flag-small.gif" alt="Dinamarca" width="100" height="50"></button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#chilihouse">Chilihouse</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
.dropbtn1:hover + .dropdown-content,
.dropdown-content:hover
{
  display: block;
}
```

Note, this is assumed that element `.dropbtn1` is followed by `.dropdown-content`

```css
.pais {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: red;
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-paises {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-paises a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-paises {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

/* changed */
/*
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
*/

.dropbtn1:hover + .dropdown-content,
.dropdown-content:hover
{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Menú</h2>
<p>Pasa el cursor por encima del botón para ver el menú.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Negocios por País</button>
  <div class="dropdown-paises">
    <div class="pais">Alemania</div>
    <button class="dropbtn1"><img src="http://chilesymaiz.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/german-flag-small.gif" alt="Alemania" width="100" height="50"></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#hola-mexico">Hola México</a>
      <a href="#komali-tortillas">Komali Tortillas</a>
      <a href="#la-mexicana-bremen">La Mexicana Bremen</a>
      <a href="#la-tortilla">La Tortilla</a>
      <a href="#mexgrocer-alemania">Mexgrocer</a>
      <a href="#delicious-food-and-drinks">Delicious Food and Drinks</a>
      <a href="#mex-al">Mex-Al</a>
      <a href="#tequila-hacienda">Tequila Hacienda</a>

      <div class="dropdown-paises">
        <div class="pais">Dinamarca</div>
        <button class="dropbtn1"><img src="http://chilesymaiz.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/dane-flag-small.gif" alt="Dinamarca" width="100" height="50"></button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#chilihouse">Chilihouse</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




>
```

Comment: Thank you. Works just fine. I was wondering how `.dropdown-content` may be hidden again if it is bypassed.  For example, if no link is clicked in "Alemania" and the user moves on to a link within "Dinamarca".

Comment: Yes, exactly! Have only the relevant dropdown items showing.

Comment: this might be tricky to do because of your layout. For example in order to get to "Dinamarca" dropdown, you must move cursor over "Alemania" button, which will open dropdown for it, than by the time you reach "Dinamarca" button, the first dropdown closes and "Dinamarca" button jumps up away from cursor and whole menu closes. So you'd need change the entire layout of your menu, or go another route where user must click at the button in order to "expand" the  menu. (this can also be done in CSS only)

Comment: Something like this, then: https://codepen.io/nick4434/pen/ewRbmL?editors=1100